# 1's and 0's to an audio file in java

Tags: java, jmf, javasound, wav

I currently have a `String` that contains 1's and 0's. I want to make an audio file out of this string, preferably in .WAV format by using Java. How do i go about it ? Are there any API's to write bytes to make a .WAV ? any tutorials/blogs ?

Thanks in advance ! cheers !

Comment: you want to convert this 0's and 1's into PCM bytes or what?

Comment: In which format is the sound information encoded in these 1s and 0s? Is it LPCM (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_pulse_code_modulation)? If so, you still need to know the parameters of the encoding (such as sample size and sample rate) to successfully extract the sound.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.jfugue.org/) is the Java third party Sound API, it has many [examples](http://www.jfugue.org/examples.html) that can be usefull for you. And Sun Java API, you can explore [here](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/sound/links.html).

Here is [Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297070/how-to-generate-sound-effects-in-java) about java sound API.

Comment: Its only text to speech conversion tool. I dont think it will understand binay string and generate wav file.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to look at the [TargetDataLine](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/TargetDataLine.html) interface. I assume you are already capable of converting your strings into a byte[] array. This byte array can be treated as the equivalent of raw audio data, but I have no idea if it will sound like anything at all interesting. With .wav format, you can choose to use 16-bit encoding (two bytes per sample) or 8-bit, too, I suppose, depending upon the size of your chars.

But given that 44100 samples per second is one of the most common rates, I would point out, that that this would require a LOT of text for very little time, if each sample is a letter!

The "key" functions in the TargetDataLine are an index into this array, and a read() method that makes use of this index as the read() method is repeatedly called. The read() method should return up to a buffer's worth of bytes with every call.

One of the methods you will need to implement, as well, will be getFormat(). I am using the following code in a simple "[Theremin](http://hexara.com/VSL/JTheremin.htm)" synthesizer, to output bytes from a table floats (using a "wave table" of around 1000 floats for a single iteration of a sound wave) to a stereo, 16-bit, 44100 fps, little-endian .wav format to a SourceDataLine for playback.

```
@Override
public AudioFormat getFormat() 
{
    AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(
        AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 
        44100, 16, 2, 4, 44100, false);
    return af;
}
```

You can learn more from the Java Tutorials. I would in particular look at the sections "Setting up a TargetDataLine" and "Reading from a TargetDataLine" in the [Capturing Audio](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html) tutorial.

But also, maybe the very start of the [sound tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/index.html) where the nature of sound data is discussed, would be very much worth your time.