# how to generate pure tones with different decibels in java?

Tags: java, audio

i need to generate pure tones with different levels of decibels (dB) in java. is there any example of how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297070/how-to-generate-sound-effects-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This http://jsresources.org/examples/OscillatorPlayer.html shows how to create pure sinusoidal (or pretty much any other) waveforms and play them. As for decibels, their relation to amplitude is `db ~ 20 * log10 (amplitude)`, i.e. `amplitude ~ 10 ^ (dB/20)`, so just calculate from that.

Comment: could you elaborate on the dB part? there are many different "scales" of dB. i assume you mean dB SPL?

Comment: @Jane Wayne: Even though people often refer to dB SPL as "sound volume", it is really always a *ratio* to some reference, see the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel). As for SPL, the reference level is pressure of [20 micropascals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure_level#Sound_pressure_level). You have to measure the SPL with a calibrated SPL meter, no way to control the absolute value directly programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

## Tones with midi Synth

You can generate tones with the synth :

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;

public class MidiSynthesizerSample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] notes = new int[]{60, 62, 64, 65, 67, 69, 71, 72, 72, 71, 69, 67, 65, 64, 62, 60};
      try {
          Synthesizer synthesizer = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
          synthesizer.open();
          MidiChannel channel = synthesizer.getChannels()[0];

          for (int note : notes) {
              channel.noteOn(note, 50);
              try {
                  Thread.sleep(200);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  break;
              } finally {
                  channel.noteOff(note);
              }
          }
      } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
}
```

Where you can set up the volume of the channels, with

```
getSetChannelVolumeMessage(int, int)
```

[http://www.springworldgames.com/rmleditor/javadoc/com/springworldgames/music/MidiUtils.html#getSetChannelVolumeMessage(int, int)](http://www.springworldgames.com/rmleditor/javadoc/com/springworldgames/music/MidiUtils.html#getSetChannelVolumeMessage%28int,%20int%29)

I don't know how to convert it to decibels, maybe it depends on your sound-card's volume level.

Comment: This doesn't really generate a pure tone, but simply plays back midi.

Comment: Yes, it plays midi sound instead of pure tone. Should I remove this?

Comment: No, but if you send me a 100 dollars I will be extremely happy! :D