# Android - Generate a tone at specific decibels

Tags: android

I need to generate a tone starting from -10 decibels and increasing with 10 at every step, till 100. A step takes 3 seconds.
The tone generation part is done and works nice, the remaining part is how to generate the tone with specific decibels.

While searching, I came across this thread: [how to generate pure tones with different decibels in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147294/how-to-generate-pure-tones-with-different-decibels-in-java)
They use the amplitude to calculate the dB. My question is, can I use the sound level instead of amplitude?

Comment: How are you defining "sound level" as distinct from "amplitude"?

Comment: By "sound level" I mean the level of your smartphone volume, when you increase the sound by pressing the two buttons: volume up, volume down.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth can this be done?